# simple-xml null to nil

Tags: java, simple-framework

I'm using the simple-xml framework (http://simple.sourceforge.net/home.php) for serializing objects.

Is there a built-in function or option, so that `null` will be converted to `nil="true"`:

XML:

```
<example xsi:nil="true"/>
```

with `xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XML-Schema-instance"`

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Not directly, but you can add this behaviour by implementing a custom [`Converter`](http://simple.sourceforge.net/download/stream/doc/tutorial/tutorial.php#converters). This allows both directions, Serialization and Deserialization.

Just don't forget the `AnnotationStrategy` (shown in the link above).

---

#### Update

```
@Element(name = "example")
@Convert(ExampleConverter.class)
private String example = "";

// ...

static class ExampleConverter implements Converter<String>
{
    // ...

    @Override
    public void write(OutputNode node, String value) throws Exception
    {
        if( value == null || value.isEmpty() == true )
        {
            node.setAttribute("xsi:nil", "true");
        }
        else
        {
            node.setAttribute("xsi:nil", value);
        }
    }
}
```

This will produce following XML if an empty value is set:

```
<SomeClass>
   <example xsi:nil="true"/>
</SomeClass>
```

Otherwise the actual value is used.

Comment: Are you sure? Because I already tried it with a converter and it didn't work. If i mark an element as required, a ValueRequiredException is thrown before the converter is called.

Comment: It's far away from being the best (or maybe even good) solution, but you can use `@Element`  and `@Convert`  annotations together to implement custom behaviour for the attribute. Checking this, however showed one limitation: `null` is not possible and some sort of "empty" value (eg. ` ""` ) for strings must be used. Not really a good solution though. Possible [Object Subtitution](http://simple.sourceforge.net/download/stream/doc/tutorial/tutorial.php#substitute) can help you here, but I haven't tested this yet.

Comment: I added some example code to my answer. Again, this solution is really hacky.

Comment: I couldn't find another way to accomplish this, and hack or not it does the job. +1 Thanks @ollo

Answer (score 0):

As a note to Ollo's answer, if you are wanting to have the value set with the normal open and closing tags, you can use node.setValue on the else as shown below:

```
public class SoapNilConverter implements Converter<String> {

@Override
public String read(InputNode node) throws Exception {
    return null;
}

@Override
public void write(OutputNode node, String value) throws Exception {
    if (value == null || value.isEmpty()) {
        node.setAttribute("xsi:nil", "true");
        node.setAttribute("xmlns:xsi", "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance");
    } else {
        node.setValue(value);
    }
}

}
```